# ¿Cómo asignar una fecha de nacimiento a una categoría de edad?

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, dataframe

Tengo una dataframe con fechas de nacimiento en `birthdate` y me gustaria matcharlas a categorias que estan en una otra dataframe. Por ejemplo:

```
    firstname   lastname    birthdate               new_professionactuelle  new_regiononame     new_communeoname
0   Ferhat      Abbas       1899-08-24 00:00:00     Ecrivain                Jijel               Bouafourna  
1   Ahmed       Ben Bella   1916-12-25 00:00:00     combattant              Oranie              Maghnia
```

Y la las clases de edad: `df['S02Q02_Age_rec'].unique()` Que esta: `array(['16-24', '25-34', '35-44', '55 or above', '45-54'], dtype=object)`

Gracias a [la respuesta de Roberto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/328791/2633) soy capaz de calcular las edades en int:

```
def calculate_age(born):
    today = date.today
    days_in_year = 365.2425
    if born != None:
        age = int((date.today() - datetime.strptime(born, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').date()).days / days_in_year)
        return age
    else:
        return born

df["age"] = df["birthdate"].apply(calculate_age)
```

¿Pero cómo se clasifican estas edades en las categorías de `df['S02Q02_Age_rec'].unique()`?

## `apply`

Intenté:

```
import re

def age_classifier(age, intervals):
    for interval in intervals:
        lower = int(re.split("\s+", interval)[0])
        upper = int(re.split("\s+", interval)[1])
        if age in range(lower,upper):
            return interval
        else:
            return age

df["age"] = df["birthdate"].apply(age_classifier(intervals = age_intervals))
```

Pero me devuelve:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-301-95b25980deea> in <module>
----> 1 df["age"] = df["birthdate"].apply(age_classifier(intervals = age_intervals))

TypeError: age_classifier() missing 1 required positional argument: 'age'
```

Entonces Dejé los intervalos codificados en el código:

```
def age_classifier(age, intervals = None):
    intervals = age_intervals
    for interval in intervals:
        lower = int(re.split("\s+", interval)[0])
        upper = int(re.split("\s+", interval)[1])
        if age in range(lower,upper):
            return interval
        else:
            return age
```

Pero me devuelve, con `df["age"] = df["birthdate"].apply(age_classifier)`:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-318-757dd6509cc9> in <module>
----> 1 df["age"] = df["birthdate"].apply(age_classifier)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   3589             else:
   3590                 values = self.astype(object).values
-> 3591                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   3592 
   3593         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-316-75658a636ff4> in age_classifier(age, intervals)
      2     intervals = age_intervals
      3     for interval in intervals:
----> 4         lower = int(re.split("\s+", interval)[0])
      5         upper = int(re.split("\s+", interval)[1])
      6         if age in range(lower,upper):

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '16-24'
```

## `np.vectorize`:

Tambien intenté:

```
np.vectorize(age_classifier)(df["birthdate"],age_intervals)
```

Pero la función parece leer sólo artículo por artículo i.e. `df["birthdate"][0]` y `16-24`.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es el formato de fecha, para parsear (convertir una caadena a un objeto datetime) necesitas que el formato coincida con el patrón indicado en `strptime`, en tu caso modifica la línea de la edad con esto:

```
days_in_year = 365.2425    
age = int((date.today() - datetime.strptime(born, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').date()).days / days_in_year)
```

He modificado el código apra almacenar en `age` un número con los años, no un objeto `timedelta` que es el que se obtiene al restar objetos `date`

Comment: Muchas gracias! ¿Sabe cómo clasificar estas edades en int en las categorías en `df['S02Q02_Age_rec'].unique()`?

Comment: Hola @IggyPass, pues no sabría decirte, no conozco mucho de dataframes :-(

Comment: ¿ La respuesta no es válida ? Me aparecía como aceptada y ahora no, ¿ hay algún error ?

Comment: En efecto, le pregunta es: _¿Cómo asignar una fecha de nacimiento a una categoría de edad?_ Por lo momento no permite clasificar estas edades en int en las categorías en `df['S02Q02_Age_rec'].unique()`

Comment: Has cambiado la pregunta totalmente, la pregunta original se responde con mi respuesta, lo que aparece ahora es un problema totalmente distinto :-)

Comment: No estoy de acuerdo, la pregunta sigue siendo la misma :p Su respuesta permite calcular las edades a partir de las fechas de nacimiento, mientras que busco desde principio a asignar una fecha de nacimiento a una categoría de edad (`['16-24', '25-34', '35-44', '55 or above', '45-54']`)

Comment: Mira, de verdad, no voy a discutir, tu programa pretende hacer lo mismo, pero el error que aparecía en tu pregunta se corrije con mi respuesta, lo que te pasa ahora debería ir en una pregunta disntia, puesto que el error es otro. SO es una web para dar soluciones a errores/situaciones concretos/as, si el error es distinto la pregunta debería serlo tb.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104374/discussion-between-iggypass-and-roberto).